# GridEx Janus: how to filter column of type DateTime by date

Tags: c#, datetime, filter, janus, gridex

I have a `janus` grid, which one of its columns is of type `DateTime`.Since I only show the date part of column data in the grid, I want to filter the column by date too. But in filter editor I have to write whole `Datetime` that is not desirable. What should I do to ignore the time part of the data in filtering the column? I set the `CompareTarget` to `Text` but it doesn't work for greater, less than or equal operation for time

```
if (columnInfo.ColumnType == DateTime)
          {
              column.CompareTarget = ColumnCompareTarget.Text;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `FormatString` property of that field to `dd/MM/yyyy`

Also you need to set the `InputMask` property to `00/00/0000`

Comment: FormatString will change the column data format but I want to change filter editor format. In fact when I write the date part and leave the filter editor, Janus automatically fill the time part of the editor by 12:00 PM

Comment: in this way greater than, not equal and other comparers except equal does't work